# Is there a bug with Firebase/ AdMob SDK? Xcode Main Thread Checker iOS 11

Tags: firebase, admob, ios10, ios11

I keep getting these warnings in iOS 11. Running the same app on devices with iOS 10 does not produce any of these warnings.

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication keyWindow]
PID: 4945, TID: 148126, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.google.admob.sdk-core-controller, QoS: 0

Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]
PID: 4945, TID: 148126, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.google.admob.sdk-core-controller, QoS: 0

Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 4945, TID: 148099, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.google.fira.worker, QoS: 9


Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:]
PID: 4945, TID: 148126, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.google.admob.sdk-core-controller, QoS: 0
```

I have got the latest pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

Comment: Up! did you fix this?

Comment: I updated to the latest Firebase version and `Google/SignIn` pod is not there anymore. It's now `GoogleSignIn`. Now no warnings...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running on iOS 11. So here are the 2 options to solve it, for people who might get this error.

**Option 1** :
When installing your dependencies using CocoaPods, instead of typing:

```
$pod install
```

you should type

```
pod install --repo-update
```

If everything works well, pod will update your old version of AdMob SDK to the latest one. In this case, you're all set and don't need to try the **Option 2**

**Option 2:**
If you read this part, it means that Pod didn't successfully update your Admob. In this case, you'll have to do it manually, which means (2 steps):

**step 1)** In your podfile, you have to comment the line and re-run pod install in the terminal

```
#pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```

to remove the previously downloaded Admob framework.

**step 2)** Download a copy of the new version of the SDK framework directly, unzip the file, and import the framework into your project in Xcode. (check the image to see how to add frameworks to your Xcode project)
[image]

image source: [Adding Frameworks to Your Xcode Project](http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/ios-ad-sdk/adding-frameworks-xcode.html)

Comment: which sdk version did you use to solve this? I'm at 7.0.0 and this is still showing up

Answer (score 0):

Simply use latest pods. But should use this command:

```
% pod update
```

Enjoy. This solved the problem in my case.